# Passing string in and back out of function

Tags: function, powershell, scope

I am really new to Powershell but I have programmed in Java and other languages.

I am trying to pass a string to a function and then have that function return the string. Below is the simple code I am trying to run:

```
#funcpass.ps1
function test {
    Param([string]$input)

    $out = $input

    return $out
}

$a = test hello world
Write-Host $a
```

I expect this to pass the string `hello world` then return the string into the variable `$a` to be printed. Instead my console returns this:

```
PS P:\test> .\funcpass.ps1

PS P:\test>
```

Is there some kind of scope error that I am encountering? Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am not sure if the version number helps, but here it is:

```
PS P:\test> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      14393  1198
```

Comment: Try not using the variable name `$input`, it's an automatic variable used for pipeline values - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables

Answer (score 7):

The `$input` parameter is **reserved**, so you have to change its name. Moreover, if you want to pass only one string to the function you have to enclose it with quotes:

```
function Run-Test {
    Param([string]$inputValue)

    $out = $inputValue

    return $out
}

$a = Run-Test "hello world"

Write-Host $a
```

FYI the `return` keyword is optional but it makes your intentions more clear as other language use `return` to indicate that something is being returned from the function. Everything sent on the pipeline inside the function (like `Write-Output`) will be returned.

Comment: Nothing worked on my system until I changed `$input` to anything else. See @TessellatingHeckler's comment on the Q :-).

Comment: @GlenLynch Also note that sodawillow used the `verb-noun` naming scheme, which is best practice for naming cmdlets and functions. Here's a [list of verbs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714428(v=vs.85).aspx) to use.

Comment: ... and (sorry) I did not use a verb from the list :-) but you get the idea.

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)